# How to make an health bar for an android game

Tags: java

I have an android game where I would like to make an health bar for my hero.
If the character has: Max_Health = 500 Current_Health = 500 then Health_Percent= 100 So the bar would be full.

[image]

How can I reduce the size of the HealthBar when my hero loses life ?

[image]

Comment: You could resize the picture. Could you paste some code of how you draw the health bar?

Comment: can you post the code of how you draw the health bar? or you load it as an image?

Comment: Write methods to your "health" class. like public void damage(int quantity){ this.current_health = this.current_health - quantity}

Comment: Hey sorry but english isn't my first language and I wasn't asking for you to do it for me. Only pointing me to a class that would do it. Someone pointed me to android's progressbar which I didn't know about. Thanks for the help !

Comment: And I know how to calculate my health, it was more about reducing the size of the picture dynamically.

Comment: Check out my earlier questions with my solution (in question): https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110086/whats-the-best-practice-for-a-progress-bar-in-opengl-es-2-0  and also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/stencil-buffer-not-working-as-expected-in-opengl-es-2-0-android

Answer (score 0):

Current_Health / Max_Health * 100 = percentage of hero for example:
250 / 500 * 100 = 50%

example code:

```
private int GetHPPercentage(int Current_Health, int Max_Health){
    return Current_Health / Max_Health * 100;
}
```